# How to parse spring post data in rest?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am developing an application in which i am using spring framework 3.1.1 and rest api. In it i have developed one rest controller which will on receiving "GET" request of url "/rest/host/{id}" will redirect the control to my view(form). Now after user fills up the form the posted data is also handled using rest. But in the method which i have written to handle post request all the parameters i am getting in one string which i want to parse and insert into the database. Can anybody tell which is the proper way to parse this spring data ? I can do it using String.split("&") but i don't think it is correct way to do that. Here is my code.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/nagios-sms-1.0/rest/snooze/host/" commandName="snoozeBean">
        <table width="100%" border="5" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <table width="50%" border="5">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="30%"><form:label path="contactNumber">Enter host address</form:label></td>
                            <td width="30%"><form:input path="contactNumber" /></td>
                            <td />
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="30%"><form:label path="snoozeTimeoutValue">Enter Snooze time</form:label></td>
                            <td width="30%"><form:input path="snoozeTimeoutValue" /></td>
                            <td />
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <div id="buttons"
                                    style="margin-left: 20Px; margin-right: 100px;">
                                    <input type="submit" value="ok" /> <input type="reset" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

REST code..

1) GET handler method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/host/{hostId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String snoozeHost(@PathVariable int hostId, ModelMap map) {

    Snooze snooze = new Snooze();
    snooze.setHost_id(hostId);
    map.put("snoozeBean", snooze);
    return "host";

}
```

2) POST handler method

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/host", method = RequestMethod.POST)   
    @ResponseBody
    public String snoozeHostOK(@RequestBody String payload) {

            // i want to parse this payload data which contains my form fields.
        System.out.println("data : " + payload);
        return payload;
    }
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of request body you can use @ModelAttribute and get all the form data bind in one pojo(snooze) filled by Spring Framework on post of the form.

You need to declare snooze in your get and post request mapped method as @ModelAttribute. That will let you get all your values from the form.

**UPDATE**

See your modified code here.

1. GET handler method

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/host/{hostId}", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
   public String snoozeHost(@PathVariable int hostId, @ModelAttribute Snooze snooze, ModelMap map) { 

   snooze.setHost_id(hostId); 
   return "host"; 

   }
   ```
2. POST handler method

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/host", method = RequestMethod.POST)    
   @ResponseBody 
   public String snoozeHostOK(@ModelAttribute Snooze snooze) { 

   // you can use the setter methods of snooze object to retrieve the field values.
   return payload; 
   }
   ```

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: can you give me some code hint ? where to write @ModelAttribute in method parameter or annotation on the method?